# Removing the last 10 characters of a file name while preserving the extension

Tags: applescript, automator

I have files that look like this

```
[RF] Happy Hour 1 [jdhf2345].mp4
[RF] Happy Hour 1 [jdhf2345].mp4
[RF] Happy Hour 1 [jdhf2345].mp4
[RF] Happy Hour 1 [jdhf2345].mp4
```

I want to make the files look like

`Happy Hour 1.mp4`

I want to remove the ID after the 1 (it may not always be a 1 but will always have an id within square brackets.

Comment: There is no question in your question :-) How should the result look like? Is AppleScript/Automator a must or would any scripting solution be fine? Are the "last 10 chars" always enclosed in `[]` or could this be anything? Don't you want to remove the trailing space as well? What do you want to happen if there is a name conflict after the shortening?

Comment: There isn’t a name conflict. I just checked

Comment: Do you want the [RF] removed from the filenames ?

Comment: I know you want an applescript, but I've been using [Name Changer](https://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/?utm_source=toolstouse.github.io), and it works great! Disclaimer: I don't work for them!

Comment: @MicroMachine  Very cool app. I’ll probably download that and use it at some point.

Comment: There's a ton of cool free mac apps out there that make everyday tasks super easy... I personally only go into coding stuff through terminal if I really need to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking two different questions here. One is "How do I remove the last 10 characters of a file name" while the other is going from `[RF] Happy Hour 1 [jdhf2345].mp4` → `Happy Hour 1.mp4`.

I'm not really sure which one to answer here so I guess I'll answer the first one??

### "How do I remove the last 10 characters of a file name"

```
set myFiles to choose file with multiple selections allowed
repeat with myFile in myFiles
    tell application "System Events"
        set myName to the characters 1 thru ((offset of "." in (name of myFile as text)) - 1) of (name of myFile as text)
        tell application "Finder"
            set myExtention to name extension of (myFile as alias)
            set myNewName to characters 1 thru (((length of myName) - 10) as number) of (myName as text)
            set name of file (myFile as text) to (myNewName & "." & myExtention as text)
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

As a shell snippet you can use

```
for i in *.mp4; do
    mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's_ \[.*\]__')"
done
```

The snippet can also be included in a shell script action in Automator if required.

Comment: Alway's loved RegEx's but never took time to learn how to create them. Good job with this one!

Comment: @josh A powerful tool those regex are :-)